# Trying to add user inputted variable into already existing list in a different file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a permanent account creation for my game that i'm making which requires you to create an account before being able to play the game. I was trying to figure out how to add it and this is the closest I managed to get to adding it to the file. What happens is that it asks for the user to input their name and then it is meant to save it to the list in the first row of my variables.py, This is what I attempted to do

```
elif menu == '3':
        enterUsername = input('Please Enter A New Username')
        with open('variables.py', 'a') as text_file:
            print ("{}".format(enterUsername)[0], file=text_file)
        continue
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and it adds the name to the bottom of the file. There is existing names already in the list so I want to add it for example

#### main.py

User inputs = "TestUserName"

#### variables.py

authUsers = ['David', 'John', 'Ali','TestUserName']

I also attempted to change the [0] on line 4 to [authUsers] but it returned with an error saying that it can only be integers. As well as this I read the documents here https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists . Thanks if anyone can help!

Comment: Why not use a database for storing account info?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about something like this, does your `variables.py` only contain `auth_users`? If not give them their own `auth_users.py` then you can import them update them and rewrite them check it out :

```
from variables import auth_users

username = input('Please Enter A New Username: ')
auth_users.insert(0, username)
something = "auth_users = {}".format(auth_users)
with open('variables.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(something)
```

Before:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ cat variables.py
auth_users = ['David', 'John', 'Ali', 'TestUserName']
```

After:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ cat variables.py
auth_users = ['Vash', 'David', 'John', 'Ali', 'TestUserName']
```

Second Run:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ cat variables.py
auth_users = ['Stampede', 'Vash', 'David', 'John', 'Ali', 'TestUserName']
```

Comment: Yeah my variables.py does have other lists. Alright i'll give this a go, just to clarify do I need to put `(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ cat variables.py` in? I've never seen that used before in python partly because i'm still learning it. But thank you very much.

Comment: haha oh no thats just my commandline, that my input to read the file and get the text so I can show you the output

Comment: the file I saved as `variables.py` and in my terminal I read the file with `cat` to show you the file updated after I ran the program

Comment: so I read it once to show you the original, than ran your code and read it again to show you the change, then read it again after I ran the code one more time, and then read the file again to show you the changes

Comment: all you need is your code, and your `variables.py` which like I said I would make your own `auth_users.py` and that way you can just do this over and over and over and not interfere with whatever else you are storing then you could do `from auth_users import auth_users`

Comment: Glad to help bud! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Create some functions to access your user file:

```
def addUser(fn, user):
    """Append user to file fn.""" 
    with open(fn,"a") as f:
        f.write(user+"\n")

def getAllUsers(fn):
    """Read file fn, return all users.""" 
    with open(fn,"r") as f:
        users=[x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if x.strip()]
    return users

filename  = "user.txt"

u = getAllUsers(filename);
print(u)                      # []

# add some users
addUser(filename,"John")
addUser(filename,"Mike")
addUser(filename,"Melitta")

u = getAllUsers(filename)     
print(u)                      # ['John', 'Mike', 'Melitta']
```

Essentially you do not modify your python-sourcecode but you create a config-file with users that you can read into a python list and process/check against.

The config file simply contains each user in one line, and can be read into your program again.

---

The file would look like:

```
John
Mike
Melitta
```

(each name, followed by a \n).

Comment: Isn't `makeSureFileExists` the same as just opening the file in `a` mode with no checks?

Comment: Right thank you very much, so if im right if I want to add a user I should do def addUser(fn, user):
 `   """Append user to file fn."""
    makeSureFileExists(fn)
    with open(fn,"a") as f:
        f.write(user+"\n")` Will this add a user once i do `addUser(filename,(enterUsername))` to my code? So I'll define these at the top of my script and then it will add it to the first row? (In a list formation)

Comment: @MadPhysicist - youre right - somehow I had in mind a did not create a file but produce an error. Thanks.

Comment: How do you enforce what sepatator already in the file and make f.write(user+"\n") work? I think you code is an example of mixing the io operations and data manipulation, which should be avoided, espacially when instructing the learners.

Comment: @EPo - the file has one name per line - seperator is the \n - which is not auto-added when writing to a file by `f.write(...)` - I am not storing the list as its `__repr__()` - instead simply one name a line. The list is recreated in `getAllUsers()`. The only way where I "mix IO and data manipulation" is when deserializing the users into a python list. You then would work with that.

Comment: @BeastFox - to make SO notice the writer of a comment: add its name prefixed by @.  In your menu on input of `'3'` you would do `addUser(fn,enterUsername)` - you would define `fn` (the filename) somewhere central. Ifyou want to check if a user is known, you use `knownUsers = getAllUsers(fn)` and then can use `if "Harry" in knownUsers: ...` to do smth.

Comment: How do you know about file? The mix of layers is not when you read the file, but when you use an unknown file + string + \n as a variable store. addUser has two pattern violations (naming and string operation), undocumented requirement about file and dim prospects of being extended if doing something else with user list, other than adding new names to it, which makes it a suboptimal recommendation for a new learner and doubtful practice for advanced user. But the accepted answer is even worse, so mayne it is just the nature of question.

Comment: @EPo - sorry? I defined the file structure: Its one username a line. I also define the filename somewhere in my code. I dont get what you mean by "pattern violation". If you want do f.e. delete from file, you write yourself a `delelteUser`. To make it cleaner you capsule all things away into a class that handles the file stuff, holds the filename as property and exposes only whats needed:`userExists(username)`, `addUser(username)`, `deleteUser(username)` for the rest of your project.

Comment: If you reference https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names - I do not follow it because I do not like underscores in my function names. This OP is also not about PEP-8 and the OP made me answer as I did - with basic file IO code, nothing fancier nor full fledged User-Maintainence

Comment: Are you expecting another inline file open operation in deleteUser(username)?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede, you supported someone in writeing from one .py file to another instead of dumping a json. Hope OP has other sources to learn than us.

Comment: @EPo It depends. If I really wanted to have a file based user management and really liked the idea that as soon that I deleted the user I wanted my file to be updated: Yes. If I kept a "session-list" of known user in my hypothetical class that manages my users I would remove him from the list there and make sure to mark it as dirty to write it to disk when appropriate - f.e. if the program closes. I might not use a simple text file for users to begin with: database, webserver with   microservices over REST, local ldap, aws actice directory. But not for this lvl of SO question.

Comment: @EPo ask OP about json and see what he says

Comment: It is totally up to the level of question to have  a list of names somewhere in the program as a variable, be able to modify it (add user, delete user) and dump it somewhere on disk as csv or json and read it back. 'Save list' is fairly basic operation, a function like save(filename, names). You would use save() both after adding or deleting a user, which makes it a good component. I honor reply in 'OP gets what he asked for' sense, but I find it hard endorse .write(name+'\n').

Comment: Comments have taken a little odd turn here... let's keep it civil and constructive folks. Thanks.